# MySQL query where result of one column row is added with next one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have used a query
 which is like

```
SELECT app_id, SUM(amount), date 
FROM abc 
GROUP BY app_id,date
```

Result is show as follows

```
1   10   1-2-2000
2   20   1-2-2000
3   30   1-2-2000
1   20   2-2-2000
2   40   2-2-2000
3   50   2-2-2000
```

I want to get desired result with new column

```
1   10   1-2-2000
2   30   1-2-2000   # sum of amount of app_id=1 and app_id=2
3   60   1-2-2000   # sum of amount of app_id=1 and app_id=2 and app_id=3
1   20   2-2-2000
2   60   2-2-2000   # sum of amount of app_id=1 and app_id=2
3  110   2-2-2000   # sum of amount of app_id=1 and app_id=2 and app_id=3
```

Comment: So you want to display the Product_ID (2) but at the same time display the amount of Product_ID 2 and 3? Very strange and illogical requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.app_id, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM abc b WHERE a.date = b.date AND b.app_id <= a.app_id) amount, a.date 
FROM abc a;
```